# Could not find valid device for node. (Tensorflow 2.1)

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, gpu

I'm trying to train a neural network using tensorflow and my GPU. When i go to the step of training:

```
K.clear_session()
history =  model.fit(training_generator,
                 epochs=35,
                 steps_per_epoch=len(train_ids),
                 callbacks= callbacks,
                 validation_data = valid_generator
                 )
```

The following error appear:

```
NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18636/1988006339.py in <module>
  5                      steps_per_epoch=len(train_ids),
  6                      callbacks= callbacks,
  ----> 7                      validation_data = valid_generator
  8                      )  
  9 

  ~\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site- 
  packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, 
  epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, 
  sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, 
  max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
  817         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
  818         workers=workers,
  --> 819         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  820 
  821   def evaluate(self,

  ~\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site- 
  packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py in fit(self, model, x, y, 
  batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, 
  class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, 
  validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
  233           max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
  234           workers=workers,
  --> 235           use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  236 
  237       total_samples = _get_total_number_of_samples(training_data_adapter)

  ~\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site- 
  packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py in 
  _process_training_inputs(model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, sample_weights, class_weights, 
  steps_per_epoch, validation_split, validation_data, validation_steps, shuffle, 
  distribution_strategy, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
  591         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
  592         workers=workers,
  --> 593         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  594     val_adapter = None
  595     if validation_data:

  ~\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site- 
  packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py in _process_inputs(model, mode, 
  x, y, batch_size, epochs, sample_weights, class_weights, shuffle, steps, 
  distribution_strategy, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
  704       max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
  705       workers=workers,
  --> 706       use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  707 
  708   return adapter

  ~\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site- 
  packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, 
  sample_weights, standardize_function, shuffle, workers, use_multiprocessing, max_queue_size, 
  **kwargs)
  950         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
  951         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
  --> 952         **kwargs)
  953 
  954   @staticmethod

  ~\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site- 
  packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, 
  sample_weights, standardize_function, workers, use_multiprocessing, max_queue_size, 
  **kwargs)
  745     # Since we have to know the dtype of the python generator when we build the
  746     # dataset, we have to look at a batch to infer the structure.
  --> 747     peek, x = self._peek_and_restore(x)
  748     assert_not_namedtuple(peek)
  749 

  ~\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site- 
  packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py in _peek_and_restore(x)
  954   @staticmethod
  955   def _peek_and_restore(x):
  --> 956     return x[0], x
  957 
  958   def _make_callable(self, x, workers, use_multiprocessing, max_queue_size):

  ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18636/1469447073.py in __getitem__(self, index)
  23 
  24         # Generate data
  ---> 25         X, y = self.__data_generation(Batch_ids)
  26 
  27         return X, y

  ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18636/1469447073.py in __data_generation(self, Batch_ids)
  62         # Generate masks
  63         y[y==4] = 3;
  ---> 64         mask = tf.one_hot(y, 4);
  65         Y = tf.image.resize(mask, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE));
  66         return X/np.max(X), Y

  ~\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\util\dispatch.py in 
  wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
  178     """Call target, and fall back on dispatchers if there is a TypeError."""
  179     try:
  --> 180       return target(*args, **kwargs)
  181     except (TypeError, ValueError):
  182       # Note: convert_to_eager_tensor currently raises a ValueError, not a

  ~\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\array_ops.py in 
  one_hot(indices, depth, on_value, off_value, axis, dtype, name)
  3643 
  3644     return gen_array_ops.one_hot(indices, depth, on_value, off_value, axis,
  -> 3645                                  name)
  3646 
  3647 

   ~\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py 
  in one_hot(indices, depth, on_value, off_value, axis, name)
  5547         pass  # Add nodes to the TensorFlow graph.
  5548     except _core._NotOkStatusException as e:
  -> 5549       _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
  5550   # Add nodes to the TensorFlow graph.
  5551   if axis is None:

  ~\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py in 
  raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
  6604   message = e.message + (" name: " + name if name is not None else "")
  6605   # pylint: disable=protected-access
  -> 6606   six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  6607   # pylint: enable=protected-access
  6608 

  ~\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

  NotFoundError: Could not find valid device for node.
  Node:{{node OneHot}}
  All kernels registered for op OneHot :
  device='GPU'; TI in [DT_UINT8]; T in [DT_HALF]
  device='GPU'; TI in [DT_INT32]; T in [DT_HALF]
  device='GPU'; TI in [DT_INT64]; T in [DT_HALF]
  device='GPU'; TI in [DT_UINT8]; T in [DT_FLOAT]
  device='GPU'; TI in [DT_INT32]; T in [DT_FLOAT]
  device='GPU'; TI in [DT_INT64]; T in [DT_FLOAT]
  device='GPU'; TI in [DT_UINT8]; T in [DT_DOUBLE]
  device='GPU'; TI in [DT_INT32]; T in [DT_DOUBLE]
  device='GPU'; TI in [DT_INT64]; T in [DT_DOUBLE]
  device='GPU'; TI in [DT_UINT8]; T in [DT_BOOL]
  device='GPU'; TI in [DT_INT32]; T in [DT_BOOL]
  device='GPU'; TI in [DT_INT64]; T in [DT_BOOL]
  device='GPU'; TI in [DT_UINT8]; T in [DT_INT32]
  device='GPU'; TI in [DT_INT32]; T in [DT_INT32]
  device='GPU'; TI in [DT_INT64]; T in [DT_INT32]
  device='GPU'; TI in [DT_UINT8]; T in [DT_INT64]
  device='GPU'; TI in [DT_INT32]; T in [DT_INT64]
  device='GPU'; TI in [DT_INT64]; T in [DT_INT64]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_UINT8]; T in [DT_INT64]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_INT32]; T in [DT_INT64]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_INT64]; T in [DT_INT64]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_UINT8]; T in [DT_INT32]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_INT32]; T in [DT_INT32]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_INT64]; T in [DT_INT32]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_UINT8]; T in [DT_UINT16]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_INT32]; T in [DT_UINT16]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_INT64]; T in [DT_UINT16]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_UINT8]; T in [DT_INT16]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_INT32]; T in [DT_INT16]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_INT64]; T in [DT_INT16]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_UINT8]; T in [DT_UINT8]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_INT32]; T in [DT_UINT8]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_INT64]; T in [DT_UINT8]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_UINT8]; T in [DT_INT8]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_INT32]; T in [DT_INT8]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_INT64]; T in [DT_INT8]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_UINT8]; T in [DT_HALF]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_INT32]; T in [DT_HALF]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_INT64]; T in [DT_HALF]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_UINT8]; T in [DT_BFLOAT16]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_INT32]; T in [DT_BFLOAT16]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_INT64]; T in [DT_BFLOAT16]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_UINT8]; T in [DT_FLOAT]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_INT32]; T in [DT_FLOAT]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_INT64]; T in [DT_FLOAT]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_UINT8]; T in [DT_DOUBLE]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_INT32]; T in [DT_DOUBLE]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_INT64]; T in [DT_DOUBLE]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_UINT8]; T in [DT_COMPLEX64]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_INT32]; T in [DT_COMPLEX64]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_INT64]; T in [DT_COMPLEX64]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_UINT8]; T in [DT_COMPLEX128]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_INT32]; T in [DT_COMPLEX128]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_INT64]; T in [DT_COMPLEX128]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_UINT8]; T in [DT_BOOL]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_INT32]; T in [DT_BOOL]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_INT64]; T in [DT_BOOL]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_UINT8]; T in [DT_STRING]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_INT32]; T in [DT_STRING]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_INT64]; T in [DT_STRING]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_UINT8]; T in [DT_RESOURCE]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_INT32]; T in [DT_RESOURCE]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_INT64]; T in [DT_RESOURCE]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_UINT8]; T in [DT_VARIANT]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_INT32]; T in [DT_VARIANT]
  device='CPU'; TI in [DT_INT64]; T in [DT_VARIANT]
  [Op:OneHot] name: one_hot/
```

I'm new using the GPU for this type of work, the code is running in jupyter notebook and is very important to use the GPU, because using the CPU will take like 3 days in training the neural network.  I hope someone can help me and tanks.

Comment: When you use `K.clear_session()` it destroys all computation graphs setup by all models. So if you do this right before training your model, it will fail. Can you move the `clear_session()` command to before the declaration of your model?

Comment: I remove K.clear_session() but still appearing the error. Thanks btw.

Comment: No prob. Can you edit your question and include the full code that you are using to define your model and start your training? It'd help a lot if you were able to produce a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The complete code is very large and I don't know how make a reproducible example. Sorry.

Comment: If you would like a particular operation to run on a device of your choice instead of what's automatically selected for you, you can use with `tf.device` to create a device context, and all the operations within that context will run on the same designated device. Train your model inside, `with tf.device('/GPU:0'):`. Thanks!